# Firm's Optimality Condition

Tags: linear-algebra, economics

If i'm given a firm's production function of

$$Y=zK^{\alpha}{N}^{1-\alpha}.$$

Then assuming $K$ is fixed and cost free, we can get our profit maximization problem of

$$\max_{{N}}zF(K^{\alpha}{N}^{1-\alpha})-wN.$$

To find the optimality condition, ${MP}_{N}=w$ , I take the partial derivative and find

$$z{F}_{N}=z(1-\alpha){K}^{\alpha}{N}^{-\alpha}=w.$$

Here is where I'm stuck.

I need to show that the optimality condition can be written as $\alpha=1-\frac{wN}{Y}$.